# Does gorm interpret the content of a struct with a logical OR?

Tags: sql, go, go-gorm

New to SQL, I am writing as an exercise an API middleware that checks if the information contained in some headers match a database entry ("token-based authentication"). Database access is based on [`GORM`](https://gorm.io/).

To this, I have defined my ORM as follows:

```
type User struct {
    ID       uint
    UserName string
    Token string
}
```

In my middleware I retrieve the content of relevant headers and end up with the variables `userHeader` and `tokenHeader`. They are supposed to be matched to the database in order to do the authentication.

The `user` table has one single entry:

```
select * from users 
// 1,admin,admintoken
```

The authentication code is

```
    var auth User
    res := db.Where(&User{UserName: userHeader, Token: tokenHeader}).Find(&auth)
    if res.RowsAffected == 1 {
        // authentication succeeded
    }
```

When testing this, I end up with the following two **incorrect** results (other combinations are correct):

- with only one header set to a correct value (and the other one not present) the authentication is successful (adding the other header with an incorrect value is OK (=auth fails))
- no headers set → authentication goes though

I expected my query to mean (in the context of the incorrect results above)

```
 select * from users where users.user_name = 'admin' and users.token = ''
 select * from users where users.user_name = '' and users.token = ''
```

and this query is correct on the console, i.e. produces zero results (ran against the database).

The ORM one, however, seems to discard non-existing headers and assume they are fine (this is at least my understanding)

I also tried to chain the `Where` clauses via

```
db.Where(&User{UserName: userHeader}).Where(&User{Token: tokenHeader}).Find(&auth)
```

but the result is the same.

**What should be the correct query?**

Comment: https://gorm.io/docs/query.html#Struct-amp-Map-Conditions -- *"NOTE When querying with struct, GORM will only query with non-zero fields, that means if your field’s value is 0, '', false or other zero values, it won’t be used to build query conditions"* ... *"To include zero values in the query conditions, you can use a map, which will include all key-values as query conditions"*.

Comment: @mkopriva: thank you - but I think it is ok in my case, right? I only need to query for two fields (the others do not matter)

Comment: You say the following gets you **incorrect** result: #1 *"with only one header set to a correct value (and the other one not present)"* #2 *"no headers set"*. According to my previous comment `#1` with a struct will generate the following query: `select * from users where users.user_name = 'admin'` and `#2` will generate: `select * from users`. Does that look ok to you? If it looks ok, then why say it's incorrect?

Comment: https://go.dev/play/p/ICuGKAYt5H2

Comment: Also note that `gorm` has debug mode in which the generated SQL gets printed into stderr, use it if you are unsure what SQL your code generates.

Comment: And just in case it's not clear, the answer to your question in the title of the post is: *No, gorm does not use logical OR for linking multiple field conditionals. However empty fields are omitted from the WHERE clause entirely.*

Comment: @mkopriva: ahhh! I missed the `''` in the text you quoted. So even, if this is an empty string (as opposed to `nil`) it will not take into account. THANK YOU, it is completely clear now. Would you be so kind and bootstrap an answer (I can complete it with links and coide). Thanks again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [gorm.io](https://gorm.io/docs/query.html#Struct-amp-Map-Conditions) documentation says the following on the use of structs in `Where` conditionals:

> When querying with struct, GORM **will only query with non-zero fields**,
> that means if your field’s value is `0`, `''`, `false` or other zero
> values, it won’t be used to build query conditions ...

The suggested solution to this is:

> To include zero values in the query conditions, you can use a map,
> which will include all key-values as query conditions ...

---

So, when the token header or both headers are empty, but you still want to include them in the `WHERE` clause of the generated query, you need to use a `map` instead of the struct as the argument to the `Where` method.

```golang
db.Where(map[string]interface{}{"user_name": userHeader, "token": tokenHeader}).Find(&auth)
```

You can use [`Debug()`](https://gorm.io/docs/session.html#Debug) to check for the generated SQL (it gets printed into stderr); use it if you are unsure what SQL your code generates